# Losing properties on viewDidLoad in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, properties

I'm trying to build a simple App where users can choose a video from a `tableViewController`, which then loads a view that plays a video. My problem is transferring the URL of the video from the `tableViewController` to the `viewController`.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_J_r8AKw0k), and I am now trying to adapt the code to play videos instead of just show images

I am creating a `viewController` from a `tableViewController` like this:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    wwfpViewController * DVC = [[wwfpViewController alloc] init];
    NSIndexPath * path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSString * theVideoName = [videoNames objectAtIndex:path.row];
    NSString * theVideoURL = [videoList objectAtIndex:path.row];
    DVC.videoNum = path.row;
    DVC.videoName = theVideoName;
    DVC.videoURL = theVideoURL;
    [DVC play];
}
```

The play message for this `viewController` is then fired, and when I `NSLog` from this message the `videoURL` is present and correct.

Then `viewDidLoad` is fired on this `viewController`, and at this point when I `NSLog` the `videoURL` it is returned as `(null)`.

I'm declaring the `videoURL` like this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * videoURL;
```

So I have a few questions:

- Does a `viewController` lose its properties when `viewDidLoad` is fired?
- Is there a better approach to sending properties to a `viewController`?
- Am I doing this completely wrong?
- And do I need to provide any more code?

Comment: How do you present the controller ?

Comment: the `viewController`? or the `tableViewController`? I have connected the two in a storyboard, is this what you mean?

Comment: The `viewController`.

Comment: If you connected them in the storyboard, then you must have used a segue. Which means that you don't have to manually alloc/init your controller and this is why you have this problem (you're creating and configuring a controller different from the one that is actually presented).

Comment: Can you please explain why the tutorial works? They connected the view via a storyboard and then manually alloc/init the controller, and it worked fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, actually the tutorial you've posted _doesn't_ do this (also, the guy stresses out that it would be in fact _wrong_ to do it this way since you use storyboards -  last minute of the video)

Comment: please see my edit, I followed the tutorial, and put my code in the correct method that he suggested (I followed both videos of the tutorial more than once, I think I get what he was stressing was wrong to do)

Comment: could you please add: NSLog(@"1.ViewController Instance: %p", self);
in VC viewdidLoad and NSLog(@"2.ViewController Instance: %p", DVC); in tableViewColntrolle (just after you alloc/init it) and check if the instances are the same? this could tell us if Alladinan war right, i guess...

Comment: ok, so in the log this appears first: 2.ViewController Instance: 0x9b7fa60, then this appears: 1.ViewController Instance: 0x9b7b540

Comment: well, so Alladinan is totally right, you set the property videoURL for the instance that you alloc/init, but its never loaded, instead the storyBoard instance load correctly, and its other instance fires its viewDidLoad (with its property videoURL = nil)... +1 for Alladinian (and yes, my old/deleted answer was wrong)

Comment: Have you `@synthesize`'d that property in your `wwfpViewController` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that despite the fact that you're using segues, you manually alloc/init a controller and set its properties (which of course is a totally different instance from the one that will be presented).

Here is what you should do instead:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Grab the destination controller
    // (it will be instantiated from the Storyboard automatically)
    wwfpViewController * DVC = (wwfpViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath * path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSString * theVideoName = [videoNames objectAtIndex:path.row];
    NSString * theVideoURL = [videoList objectAtIndex:path.row];
    // Set the properties
    DVC.videoNum = path.row;
    DVC.videoName = theVideoName;
    DVC.videoURL = theVideoURL;
    [DVC play]; // Why don't you call this on viewDidLoad of the destination controller?
}
```

**PS:** In Objective-C you usually name the ivars (by convention) so that they start with a small letter and the Classes with a capital one. So `WWFPViewController` and `dvc` would be more appropriate names in your case.

Comment: This worked. Many thanks for your help and patience through all of this! Im still trying to figure this language out and your comments and answers have been very informative! I will bare in mind the name conventions you have mentioned in the future.

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm glad that it helped you. Enjoy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You are mistakenly initializing and configuring new controller instance, which is released once the `- (void)prepareForSegue:` method ends and is never actually used. Another controller instance is automatically initilized by segue and then presented. That is the reason you see "null", its not really configured.

If you are using segues, you must configure destination view controller provided by `UIStoryboardSegue` instance instead of creating new one.

Something like this:

```
wwfpViewController * DVC = (wwfpViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
```