# viewDidLoad get called after init

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

My main `ViewController` is embedded in `navigation controller` and in my `ViewController` i have `CollectionView` when i click on `custom collectionViewCell` it goes to next `View Controller` using `push segue` and in my second `View Controller` i have `UIImage` property.

I'm implementing following code when i click on `Collection ViewCell`

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Why did you called me?");
    DetailViewViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewViewController alloc] init];

    ALAsset *asset = self.assets[indexPath.row];
    ALAssetRepresentation *defaultRep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[defaultRep fullScreenImage] scale:[defaultRep scale] orientation:0];

    [dvc initWithImage:image];

}
```

`initWithImage` Method

```
-(id) initWithImage:(UIImage *)imageName {
    self = [super init];
    NSLog(@"inithWithImage Called");

    self.image = imageName;

    return self;
}
```

**Problem**: problem is `initWithImage` get called before `viewDidLoad`. In initWithImage method i'm setting my property `UIImage` equal to `image`. But when i check in `viewDidLoad`
my property `UIImage` is equal to `null`

How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: set `image` as a property of `DetailViewViewController`, here you init the `DetailViewViewController` twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image need to be a property of DetailViewController instance that is used by the segue, check out "prepare for segue"

The problem is that despite the fact that you're using segues, you manually alloc/init a controller and set its properties (which of course is a totally different instance from the one that will be presented).

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104649/losing-properties-on-viewdidload-in-objective-c) and [here](http://nscookbook.com/2013/01/ios-programming-recipe-5-passing-values-between-segues-with-prepareforsegue/)

Comment: `self.image = imageName;` you can see image is property(nonatomic and strong)

Comment: i read the the answer and make a property of `DetailViewController` and in `prepareforSegue` initiliazed that property and using that property  i called init but viewDidLoad get Called after init, but this time my property `UIImage` not equal to `null`. but still image not showing strange

Comment: Well atleast you are using the correct approach-. are you properly allocating the image?

Comment: Yes, i think problem is viewDidLoad getting called after init

Comment: You should resort to using either init or initWithImage, not both then.

But when using segues I prefer using my approach and then doing something with the passed property in viewDidLoad for instance...

Answer (score 2):

Your initialising the `DetailViewViewController` in a wrong way. Try:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    ALAsset *asset = self.assets[indexPath.row];
    ALAssetRepresentation *defaultRep = [asset defaultRepresentation];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[defaultRep fullScreenImage] 
                                         scale:[defaultRep scale] 
                                   orientation:0];

    DetailViewViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewViewController alloc] initWithImage:image];

    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong in that? i tried that but no effect

Answer (score 0):

Just have an variable declared in DetailViewViewController and initialize with the Image pathstring / image name to it while allocating the instance of the same. In viewdidload of DetailViewViewController using the pathstring / image name set it to imageview component.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"Why did you called me?");
    DetailViewViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewViewController alloc] init];

    //get the path of image
    ....
    ....
    dvc.variablename = imagepath / imagename
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please check the imagepath string in viewdidload of DetailViewViewController?